# printf function

Tags: php

I want to create an output as follows using the printf function:

```
***********************************************************************************
```

Here is my code for this line:

```
printf("%'*c <br>\n",42);
```

where 42 is the specified ASCII code for *.  this command only generates one * not 100 of *.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_repeat('*', 100) . '<br>';
```

There is no need for `printf`, since you are not doing any *formatting*. You're just printing some literal stuff.

Comment: actually i want to do some formating and i want to put results in an ooutput file using fprintf function.

Comment: @BlueSky: OK; post your actual problem then, so that we're not talking past each other.

Comment: $a=fgets($testin);
 fprintf($testout, "%'*c <br>\n",42,$a);
 fprintf($testout, "%s <br>\n",$a);
 fprintf($testout, "%'*c <br>\n",42,$a); in the first and last lines I want to print 100 of *.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the %,

```
 printf("\%'*c <br>\n",42);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php). Code would be as follows:

`<?php
echo str_repeat("*", 100);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but what I think you're trying to do is;

```
printf("%'*100s <br>\n", "");
```

which will print 100 asterisks followed by an HTML line break.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the others have mentioned, you can use str_repeat() to do this.

However, if you need to use printf(), you can use %s in the format, and pass str_repeat in as a variable.  So it'd be something like this:

```
printf("%s <br>", str_repeat('*', 42));
```